# ggplot2 graph and overriding

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have recently started using `ggplot2` so, I once again apologize for posting basic question.

I read about this code in one of the help pages. This code nicely plots line graph and the average with red dot:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(trans, cty)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red", size = 4)
```

I thought of simplifying this a bit by overriding the contents of `geom_point()` and using `stat="summary"`

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(trans, cty)) +
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean", colour = "red", size = 4) +
```

However, the above code doesn't work. Can someone please help me why above code doesn't work? Specifically, it only plots the red dot (mean point). I don't see the scatterplot although I have used `geom_point()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ggplot()` defines `aes()`, but you are overriding them using the `geom` layer.

In the first case, `geom_point()` completes the plotting of the points, and `stat_summary()` did the part of adding summary statistics layer to your graph.

But, when you define `stat = "summary"`, you tell `geom_point()` to plot summary statistics instead of the data points.

Head over the `ggplot2` documentation and read how mapping works within this ecosystem: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Comment: Thanks Pj_. That helped. I added geom_point(), and it worked well! Thank you so much.

Comment: @ss0208535 Glad that I could help! :) If the answer helped you, can you please accept it?